# Trigger for status update to send a patch method in Azure DevOps

Tags: json, rest, azure-devops

Have been working on the integration between Azure DevOps Services and ServiceNow. Our goal is to send Change Requests from ServiceNow to Azure DevOps, where they would become Features or User Stories. Whenever there is some update on Azure DevOps, that update should be sent to ServiceNow, and vice versa.
The idea is to work with REST API.

From our investigation, we have found that it is possible to send updates to other applications through Web Hooks. We are still not sure if this will suite our needs and if we are able to work with this. The problem is that the webhooks only support the HTTP method POST while Service Now requests PATCH to update on it’s side. Is this correct is there any way of creating webhooks with PATCH method?

Other way that we can integrate is to create some software that will send response needed. However, we cannot seem to find a way to automate this response. As I understood, it will generate response only when the script run, not when work item is updated. Is there any way to trigger the sending of a json file with all information within the work item whenever the work item state is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can try to  create a custom service hook. Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-service-hook?view=azure-devops#tutorial-overview---custom-consumer-service) you can refer to .

Marketplace provides an extension([Azure DevOps Service Hooks DSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-ServiceHooks-DSL)) . This extension framework is designed to ease the development of your own REST Web Hook web site to do this type of integration. It does this by providing a MVC WebAPI endpoint and a collection of helper methods, implemented as an extensible Domain Specific Language (DSL), for common processing steps and API operations such as calling back to the TFS/VSTS server that called the endpoint or accessing SMTP services.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to trigger the sending of a json file with all
> information within the work item whenever the work item state is
> updated?

I am not sure if it is possible to trigger that.

But there is a [ServiceNow DevOps extension](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-devops/page/product/enterprise-dev-ops/task/config-dev-ops-extensions-azure.html#config-dev-ops-extensions-azure) for the integration between Azure Devops and Snow. You may use that.

Comment: Thanks, the extension you mention targets the build and release notifications. I would like to trigger a PATCH method whenever a workitem is changed. The problem is that the webhooks in Azure DevOps Services only allows POST method, but I need a PATCH method to be able to do a status change in Service Now.